# Clear filter in csysdig

Tags: monitoring, system-monitoring

How is it possible to reset the  filter in csysdig and get the default that is present when the program starts?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press the BackSpace key repeatedly to step backwards through csysdig selection history, which csysdig refers to as "drill up".